# Insert plugin into a fluid template?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

The extension [ke_search](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ke_search) has a search field plugin that I want to insert into my fluidtemplate and show on every page. I am very new in this and don't know how to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to insert a simple search field that points to a result page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the Plugin to an typoscript lib:

```
lib.searchMask < tt_content.list.20.your_plugin
```

(Please search the location of the plugin in the typoscript browser)

In your fluid you can use `f:cObject`to include it:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.searchMask" />
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to configure it with this method? There's a field called resultPage (in flexform) and its value should be 138

Comment: I don't know ke_search. By "default" settings should be working by setting ```lib.searchMask.settings.resultPage = 138``` or globaly by ```plugin.extension_key.settings.resultPage = 138```.

Comment: I've used this approach with powermail. It's not exactly inserting the plugin via ts, but copying a plugin from backend into a template. which also works - but it's not the same

Comment: `# Create TypoScript Object
lib.searchbox_plugin = COA_INT
lib.searchbox_plugin {
  10 < plugin.tx_kesearch_pi1
  10.resultPage = 123
  10.cssFile = EXT:ke_search/res/ke_search_pi1.css
  10.loadFlexformsFromOtherCE = 123456 // Search form plugin UID
}`

Example taken from: https://t3terminal.com/blog/typo3-ke-search/

Answer (score 1):

In general you have three possibilities to include special content in all your pages:

1. put the HTML hardcoded in your template (typoscript, marker, fluid)
2. use a typoscript object which can be inserted in your template
3. use typoscript to render a special CE on a special page
4. use a special column in your (BE) page layout, where the content is inherited to subpages

Solution 1 has the drawback of being very static and you might miss the opportunity to configure dynamically (e.g. links, spamprotection, ...)

Solution 2 could be complicated if you want a plugin and the plugin can not be configured by pure typoscript (or the configuration collided with the configuration of the plugin in the main content)

Solution 3 needs a special (unvisible) page where the CE is stored and can be edited. In your TS you render it with the CONTENT object and use a hard coded uid. You need to remember that special place and special CE. (an editor might 'replace' the CE and wonder why it goes missing)

Solution 4 enables you to use 'normal' editor functionality (configure the plugin as a CE), but might cost some more rendering time because of the sliding and you need to define a special column with additional handling.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bernd's answer, this is the simplest solution using 1) with TypoScript and some constants for the simplest `ke_search` input field, but this could be even hardcoded in your html template and it would still work. It's just a GET query that's being sent to the result page – where you set the searchbox again by page plugin.

```
temp.search = TEXT
temp.search.value (

<form action="index.php" id="site-search" name="xajax_form_kesearch_pi1" id="xajax_form_kesearch_pi1" method="get">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" name="tx_kesearch_pi1[sword]" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="{$llSearch}" class="button">
        <input type="hidden" value="{$pidResultPage}" name="id"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="tx_kesearch_pi1[page]" id="pagenumber">
      </form>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is on more option if you only want the search input but no results e.g. in a header or footer. I could only test this in a TYPO3 11.5 with indexed_search though! The general approach might also work with ke_search.

My TypoScript setup:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings {
    targetPid = 17
    displayAdvancedSearchLink = 0
}

lib.search = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.search{
    file = EXT:mysitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials/IndexedSearch/Form.html
    settings < plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings
}

// Custom templates for indexed search.
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.view {
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Templates/
        10 = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.view.templateRootPath}
        20 = EXT:mysitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/IndexedSearch/
    }

    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Partials/
        10 = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.view.partialRootPath}
        20 = EXT:mysitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials/IndexedSearch/
    }
}
```

Then I copied `public/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Resources/Private/Partials/Form.html` to my folder `public/typo3conf/ext/mysitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials/IndexedSearch/Form.html`.

In the copied file you have to add some attributes to the form tag: `extensionName="IndexedSearch"`, `pluginName="pi2"`and `controller="Search"` so that in the end the form tag looks like this:

```
<f:form action="search" method="post" pageUid="{settings.targetPid}" extensionName="IndexedSearch" pluginName="pi2" controller="Search">
```

Now you can add this to any fluid template to add a search input:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A more comprehensive way (IMHO) for adding a plugin in a fluid template.

Add the plugin in TypoScript :

```
lib.insertPlugin = USER
lib.insertPlugin {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Extensionname
  pluginName = Pluginname
  vendorName = Vendorname
}
```

Call this TypoScript object in your fluid template :

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.insertPlugin" />
```