# TYPO3 include plugin in fluid

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18, do you know how include extension plugin right on fluid template? I found this link [Insert plugin into a fluid template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787318/insert-plugin-into-a-fluid-template)

but I can't understand how I can find path to my plugin ? There described something about some typoscript browser.. Can you tell me how to do it, please )

Comment: Normally all plugins are registered in the same location in typoscript, tt_content.list.20 - you'll just have to add your pluginname tt_content.list.20.your_plugin_name. If you're unsure you can use the typoscript object browser (in the backend module "template") to look the exact path up.

Comment: yes that's works )

Comment: @deadfishli: make it a real answer. Mikael: accept (and vote) the answer

Answer (score 0):

Normally all plugins are registered in the same location in typoscript, tt_content.list.20 - you'll just have to add your pluginname tt_content.list.20.your_plugin_name. If you're unsure you can use the typoscript object browser (in the backend module "template") to look the exact path up.